# Using two Cisco Aironet 1100's

Tags: wifi

Is it possible to use two of these both providing connectivity to the same network name for additional signal by having one plugged into a hot data port and having the other only powered by the AC? It seems to have worked for one day, then it stopped and I have the middle light blinking, and the other "hot" one solid in the middle and flashing rapidly on the last light.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the one that's plugged into the network with a root role and set up the other one as a repeater.

A quick google search turns up these useful pages:

- http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/wireless/access_point/12.2_11_JA/configuration/guide/s11rep.html
- http://www.hh.se/download/18.2e7e912511d7b60146080008686/Configure+AP+as+a+Repeater.pdf